# Outbound Traffic from Private Subnet in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Can I download and install patches from Internet using Route53, without having NAT Gateway and IGW?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be a little confused regarding what Route53 is:

> Amazon Route 53 is a highly available and scalable cloud Domain Name System (DNS) web service.
> [Source](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/)

So, it has nothing to do with downloading patches. You can use it to handle your domains, and it can work nicely with several AWS services.

Now, regarding your question. If you want an EC2 instance to access the Internet and download its security patches, you will need an Internet Gateway configured on the VPC of the instance. On the other hand, the NAT Gateway is only necessary if your instance is configured on a private subnet. A private subnet doesn't have direct access to the Internet Gateway, so you need to provide a NAT Gateway to allow your instances to reach it. EC2 instances in public subnets can be assigned public IPs. An instance with a Public IP can access the Internet directly through the Internet Gateway without needing a NAT Gateway.

Another resource you are going to have to configure is Route Tables. Each subnet is assigned to a single Route Table. Once attached, it will use the routes define on the Route Table to handle their instances traffic. A Route Table that handles private subnets will have a `default route` pointing to a NAT Gateway. And a public Route Table will have a `default route` pointing directly to the Internet Gateway. Bear in mind that the NAT Gateway should always be instantiated on public subnets.

Take a look at the following documentation site for more information:

[VPC Internet Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)

[VPC Subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html)

[VPC Route Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Route53 is a DNS service and its function is DNS resolution. You need NAT Gateway for outbound internet access from private subnet